# Langchain pandas agent unable to run pandas commands

Tags: python, pandas, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

I'm trying to use langchain's pandas agent on python for some development work but it goes into a recursive loop due to it being unable to take action on a thought, the thought being, having to run some pandas code to continue the thought process for the asked prompt on some [sales dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/aungpyaeap/supermarket-sales) (sales.csv).

here is the below code

```
import os
os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = 'sk-xxx'
from langchain.agents import create_pandas_dataframe_agent
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sales.csv')
llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0.0,model_name='gpt-3.5-turbo')
pd_agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(llm, df, verbose=True)
pd_agent.run("what is the mean of the profit?")
```

and well the response it gives is as below  (i replaced ``` with ----)

```
> Entering new  chain...
Thought: We need to calculate the profit first by subtracting the cogs from the total, and then find the mean of the profit.
Action: Calculate the profit and find the mean using pandas.
Action Input:
----
df['Profit'] = df['Total'] - df['cogs']
df['Profit'].mean()
----
Observation: Calculate the profit and find the mean using pandas. is not a valid tool, try another one.
Thought:I need to use python_repl_ast to execute the code.
Action: Calculate the profit and find the mean using pandas.
Action Input: `python_repl_ast` 
----
df['Profit'] = df['Total'] - df['cogs']
df['Profit'].mean()
----
Observation: Calculate the profit and find the mean using pandas. is not a valid tool, try another one.
Thought:I need to use `python` instead of `python_repl_ast`.
Action: Calculate the profit and find the mean using pandas.
Action Input: `python`
----
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
df['Profit'] = df['Total'] - df['cogs']
df['Profit'].mean()
----
.
.
.
.
.
.
Observation: Calculate the profit and find the mean using pandas. is not a valid tool, try another one.
Thought:

> Finished chain.
```

`'Agent stopped due to iteration limit or time limit.'`

Now my question is why is it not using the python_repl_ast tool to do the calculation?
I even changed this agent's tool's description (python_repl_ast ) which was

*A Python shell. Use this to execute python commands. Input should be a valid python command. When using this tool, sometimes output is abbreviated - make sure it does not look abbreviated before using it in your answer.*

into

*A Python shell.   Use this to execute python commands and profit, mean calculation using pandas. Input should be a valid python command. When using this tool, sometimes output is abbreviated - make sure it does not look abbreviated before using it in your answer.*

But it did not help. Also i noticed when the `python_repl_ast` is initialized into my agent the dataframe is loaded into it's local variables `tools = [PythonAstREPLTool(locals={"df": df})]` so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a problem with dtypes. Try using df.convert_dtypes(infer_objects=True).

Comment: with a little bit of prompt template optimization, the agent goes into the thought process  but fails because the only tool it needs to use is `python_repl_ast` but sometimes the agent comes up with the idea that the tool it needs to use is 
`OutputParserException: Could not parse LLM output: 'I need to use the 'python_repl_ast' tool to calculate the profits for each day.'`
which isnt a valid tool hence fails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the information you provide in Langchain agents is supposed to be for prompt context.

Add the below code to provide custom information for your agent.

```
query = "what is the mean of the profit?"
query = query + " using tool python_repl_ast"
pd_agent.run(query)
```

It worked for me.

Comment: I ended up building my own text to SQL ai agent using langchain, it works 100x better, will share the project on github soon.